# Few minutes with full access to my linux machine

Tags: linux, security

I have made a mistake of allowing root access to my linux machine (one of the lines in pam modules) on a private local network for a couple of minutes. On the other hand, apart from a few ports, everything is filtered or dropped in my firewall + there're not many services listening.

Should I be concerned about security?

I can't see any strange behaviour of my machine, no suspicious network traffic and processes.

This is more of a theoretical question, but I wonder how big of a risk something like this could be for a normal home user.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by a few minutes? Can you provide more detail on how your PAM configuration was/is configured to allow this to happen?

Comment: It's a very small chance that anyone has hacked your system, since it was not open to the Internet(?). However if you have any doubts that it might have still happened, you should re-install your system, if you can do it with easily or with small effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that was when you were connected to your home network, then very, very unlikely. The router between your PC and the internet is one-way, normally only the connections initiated on your local network will go through, and your PC is not reachable from the internet, because that requires a connection initiated from outside your local network.

Now, if there is a hacker in the household...